# I have a 450 UPS, will it be enough to let me safely power down my 600watt psu computer?

Tags: backup, power-supply, ups

I don't need to use it, just turning it off if a power outage happens is enough for me.

Comment: If you have the UPS with you, why don't you try disconnecting the mains and turning the PC?

Answer (score 3):

This question is hard to answer, so I cannot provide you with the answer, other than the necessary information to reach a conclusion yourself.

You see, a 600Watt PSU does not draw 600 Watt continuously. It can transfer up to 600 Watt of power into the machine if the load is high enough, but if your computer is idle, it will more likely draw only 200 watt of power, maybe less, maybe a bit more.

In order to find out how much watt your computer really uses, you need to hook up a meter that will find out how much power your pc consumes.

That said, if your pc does use more than 450 Watt at the moment that there is a power outage, the UPS will not be able to take the load and the pc will be turned off the same as if there was no UPS. The more watt a pc uses, the faster it drains the battery, but if you go over the limit the UPS can handle, it just can't provide enough power at all and will simply fail.

Comment: Aren't watt ratings on PSU's for the DC side, not the AC side?

Comment: @Moab Watt ratings, yes... actual watt usage, no.

Comment: @Moab Yes. However much the DC side is supplying, the AC side is using **more** than that, by a factor of at least 10% and more likely 20 or 30 if you're lucky. Be aware that the efficiency ratings on PC PSUs are taken only at one load, usually around 80% of max, and the PSU's efficiency will drop off markedly on either side of that.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you're using all of that PSU. You should really size your UPS so that its wattage rating is at least twice your typical load.

On "home and small office" class UPSs the power rating is furthermore for peak only. A "450 watt" UPS should not be counted on for more than about 300 watts continuous. Otherwise they will overheat and die. So, when power fails, your UPS monitor software should immediately kill e.g. games or video rendering jobs, then do an orderly shutdown of the OS, which should take no more than a minute. You could try setting it to go into hibernation if you think it can be done fast enough.

The best way to know the PC's actual power usage at the AC outlet is with a meter like the Kill-a-Watt (around $20 in US stores).